# IMG not loading on webview

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having trouble parsing the img tag on `webview`. the

tag works and heading but not img. I'm parsing this Html tags to `webview`

```
fun loadAnnouncement() {
           val url = url
           val client = OkHttpClient()
           val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
           client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
               override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                   val body = response.body?.string()
                   runOnUiThread {
                       if (body != null) {
                           showAnnouncement(body)
                       }
                   }
               }

               override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                   println("Failed to load: ${e.message}")
               }
           })
   }


fun showAnnouncement(message: String) {
       val dialog = Dialog(this)
       dialog .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
       dialog .setCancelable(false)
       dialog .setContentView(R.layout.alert_announcement)
       val close = dialog .findViewById(R.id.btn_close) as Button
       val webView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.webView_announcement) as WebView
       webView.loadData(message, "text/html", "UTF-8")
       close.setOnClickListener {
           dialog .dismiss()
       }
       webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
       webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
       webView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
       webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
       dialog .show()
   }
```

**This is the body that i'm trying to load from webview (URL)**

`"<p>Paragraph</p><p><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/large/google_photos_1526539307005.jpg\"><br></p><p><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/large/google_photos_1526539307005.jpg\"></p>"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to access internet resources `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`?

If so, try making your `message` to look like:

`"<html><head></head><body><p>Paragraph</p><p><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/large/google_photos_1526539307005.jpg\"><br></p><p><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/large/google_photos_1526539307005.jpg\"></p></body></html>"`